# PHP from validation and login script

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this code of validating a login script, and I have another code of checking the user info once he enters the email address and the password to log in however I can't find a way to connect these tow scripts together 
I want the form to be validated at first then after successful validation the info gets checked in the a login-process.php where the entered info get checked in the database

login.php

```
    <?php
$emailErr = $passwordErr = "";
$email = $password = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $emailErr = "*email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "*ivalid email format";
    }
  }

if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
  $passwordErr = "*password is required";
} else {
  $password = test_input($_POST['password']);
  }

}

//the function to filter the input
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripcslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>user login</title>
  <link href="login-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
  .error {
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <p>please either login or <br> <a href="regestir.php">click here to regestir</a>
    <form method="POST" action="login-process.php"  name="loginform">
      <span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
    </div>
    <body>
      </html>
```

login-process.php

```
<?php
include('user-config.php');
session_start();

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);


if(isset($email) && isset($password)) {          //check if it is set or not
  $sql = "select * from data where email = '$email' and password = '$password' ";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($count == 1) {
    $_SESSION['useremail'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['userpassword'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
    $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender'];

    #print_r($_SESSION);          show the values stored in the sessions
    header("location: welcome.php");
  } else {
    echo 'username or passwrod is incorrect';
  }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: check if email error and password error is empty. If they are, redirect to login-process.php with a `header(location:)`

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords. Hash. Don't use `test_input`, I don't know when that function got popular. Parameterize and escape on outputting.

Comment: @chris85 that happens when people use [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp)...

Comment: what's wrong with w3schools @Condorcho, it's a great source of information

Comment: Ugh, no it's not @PuzantBakjejian